# Unable to add EF Core migration using composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity

I have the following entities:

```
public sealed class CanonicalMake : EntityBase<MakeId>
{
    private CanonicalMake() { }

    public MakeId MakeId { get; private init; }
    protected override MakeId Id => MakeId;

    public string Name { get; private init; }

    //Other static methods Create, Validate etc.
}

public sealed class CanonicalModel : EntityBase<ModelId>
{
    private CanonicalModel() { }

    public ModelId ModelId { get; private init; }
    protected override ModelId Id => ModelId;

    public string Name { get; private init; }

    //Other static methods Create, Validate etc.
}

public class AircraftSighting: EntityBase<AircraftSightingId>
{
    private AircraftSighting() { }

    public AircraftSightingId AircraftSightingId { get; private init; }
    protected override AircraftSightingId Id => AircraftSightingId;

    //There may be zero or one canonical model for each sighting      
    public ModelId? CanonicalModelId { get; private init; }
        
    //Other static methods Create, Validate etc.        
}
```

And the following strongly typed identifiers

```
public class MakeId : IdentifierBase 
{ 
    public MakeId(): base() { }
    public MakeId(Guid guid): base(guid) { }
}

public class ModelId : ValueObjectBase
{
    private ModelId() { }

    public Guid MakeGuid { get; private init; }
    public Guid ModelGuid { get; private init; }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return MakeGuid; 
        yield return ModelGuid;
    }

    public static ModelId CreateFromMakeId(MakeId makeId, Guid modelGuid)
    {
        return new ModelId
        {
            MakeGuid = makeId.Guid,
            ModelGuid = modelGuid
        };
    }

    public static ModelId CreateFromMakeId(MakeId makeId)
    {
        return new ModelId
        {
            MakeGuid = makeId.Guid,
            ModelGuid = Guid.NewGuid()
        };
    }
}

public class AircraftSightingId : IdentifierBase 
{
    public AircraftSightingId() : base() { }
    public AircraftSightingId(Guid guid) : base(guid) { }
}
```

And my entity configurations are as follows

```
public class CanonicalMakeEntityConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CanonicalMake>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CanonicalMake> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.MakeId);
        builder.Property(e => e.MakeId).HasConversion(
            makeId => makeId.Guid,
            guid => new MakeId(guid));
        
        builder.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class CanonicalModelEntityConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CanonicalModel>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CanonicalModel> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.ModelId);
        builder.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class AircraftEntityConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AircraftSighting>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AircraftSighting> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.AircraftSightingId);

        builder.Property(e => e.AircraftSightingId).HasConversion(
            id => id.Guid,
            value => new AircraftSightingId(value));

        builder.Property(e => e.CanonicalModelId).HasConversion(
            modelId => new { MakeGuid = modelId!.MakeGuid, ModelGuid = modelId!.ModelGuid },
            value => ModelId.CreateFromMakeId(new MakeId(value.MakeGuid), value.ModelGuid));

        builder.HasOne<CanonicalModel>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CanonicalModelId);
        
        //Other mappings
    }
}
```

But when I try to add a migration via EF Core, I get the following error:

> The '<>f__AnonymousType0<Guid, Guid>' property 'AircraftSighting.CanonicalModelId' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type. Consider converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information. Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

Ok it looks like using composite keys via Value Objects is not supported and is a limitation at present in EF Core. The [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#limitations) reads

> There is currently no way to spread a conversion of one property to
> multiple columns or vice-versa. Please vote () for GitHub issue
> #13947 if this is something you need.

In addition to the mentioned [GitHub issue #13947](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13947), I found related: [#15962](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15962) and [#16450](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16450)

This is such a basic necessity to keep the domain model clean I'm surprised its lacking in EF Core still but hopefully we'll have this feature in a future release

Comment: The error says "the database provider does not support this type". What provider are you using?

Comment: @nikstra I'm using ms sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the error as EF is trying to create a column with the type `<>f__AnonymousType0<Guid, Guid>` which is not an existing datatype on the server.

Since `CanonicalModelId` already is of type `ModelId`, wouldn't the following work?

```cs
builder.Property(e => e.CanonicalModelId).HasConversion(
    modelId => modelId,
    value => ModelId.CreateFromMakeId(new MakeId(value.MakeGuid), value.ModelGuid));
```

Comment: I tried the above but I get a similar error this time: `The 'ModelId' property 'AircraftSighting.CanonicalModelId' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type. Consider converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information. Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'`

Comment: Ok I think this is a limitation in EF Core at the time of writing. See my edit in the original question